# Sphinx returning inconsistent results when searched through command line vs. using php api

Tags: php, sphinx

I am making a boolean query i.e. `"hello | world"` . when I make this query through the command line, it gives correct results i.e. the documents which contain both of these terms are shown on the top and the ones containing only one of them are shown in the bottom.

However, when I make the same query from php api of sphinx, it gives wrong results. I am making the query from command line using:

> C:\sphinx-1.10\bin\search --config C:\sphinx-1.10\sphinx.conf.in "hello | world" --limit 3

This returns the correct results now, the php code I am using is:

```
<?php


include('/sphinx-1.10/api/sphinxapi.php');

  $cl = new SphinxClient();
  $cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_BOOLEAN);
  $cl->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE);
  $cl->SetLimits(0,3);

  $result = $cl->Query( "hello | world", 'sample' );

  if ( $result === false ) {
      echo "Query failed: " . $cl->GetLastError() . "<br/>";
  }
  else {
      if ( $cl->GetLastWarning() ) {
          echo "WARNING: " . $cl->GetLastWarning() . "<br/>";
      }
      if ( ! empty($result["matches"]) ) {
          foreach ( $result["matches"] as $doc => $docinfo ) {
                echo "$doc <br/>";
          }
      }
  }
?>
```

The above returns wrong results.

Can someone please guide me with what am I doing wrong??

Comment: What means "wrong"? Could you provide output of script?

Comment: And firstly your script and sphinx from console, may have different sort or match settings

Comment: well the command line returns ids 51, 69, 102 .. whereas, the php api returns 201, 256, 415 ... all the 6 rows are valid but what i don't understand is why aren't the same results returned

Comment: @user633696 your script and sphinx from console, may have different sort or match settings

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2 matching mode instead?
Perhaps it's the boolean mode that does the damage http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#boolean-syntax